# Change position of marginal axis in seaborn jointplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Seaborn by default plots the marginal distributions on the top and right of the main plot. Is it possible to change this location (e.g., to bottom and left)?

A minimal example, using the seaborn documentation:

```
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
g = sns.jointplot(x="total_bill", y="tip", data=tips)
```

gives...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is a bit tedious, but you can adapt [this example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/axes_grid1/scatter_hist_locatable_axes.html) to your needs. It uses a `make_axes_locatable` divider. Changing this from top to bottom and from right to left is no problem, but then you need to change the labelling and ticks on all axes.

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
x = tips["total_bill"]
y = tips["tip"]

fig, axScatter = plt.subplots(figsize=(5.5, 5.5))
fig.subplots_adjust(.1,.1,.9,.9)

axScatter.scatter(x, y)

divider = make_axes_locatable(axScatter)
axHistx = divider.append_axes("bottom", 1.2, pad=0.1, sharex=axScatter)
axHisty = divider.append_axes("left", 1.2, pad=0.1, sharey=axScatter)

# make some labels invisible
axHistx.tick_params(labelbottom=False, bottom=False, 
                    left=False, labelleft=False, right=True, labelright=True)
axHisty.tick_params(labelleft=False, left=False, 
                    bottom=False, labelbottom=False, top=True, labeltop=True)
axHistx.invert_yaxis()
axHisty.invert_xaxis()
axScatter.xaxis.tick_top()
axScatter.yaxis.tick_right()
axScatter.xaxis.set_label_position('top')
axScatter.yaxis.set_label_position('right')
axScatter.set(xlabel="Total Bill", ylabel="Tip")

axHistx.hist(x, bins=16, density=True)
axHisty.hist(y, bins=16, density=True, orientation='horizontal')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Depending on your taste, you can also do: `g, axs = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(5.5, 5.5),
    gridspec_kw={'height_ratios':[3, 1],
    'width_ratios':[1, 3]}, constrained_layout=True)
axHisty, axScatter, junk, axHistx = axs.flatten()

junk.remove()
`